# Modify value of ng-show from true to false once redirected to home page from login page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie to angularjs and had a problem to solve where I had to modify the value of `ng-show="false"` to `ng-show="true"` when user is redirected to `home page` after he/she is logged in successfully!!

here is what i'm trying to do:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, ..., showmenu)
{
      $scope.dropdown = showmenu.hide;
      ....
}
.factory('showmenu', function() {
  return {
      show : 'true',
      hide : 'false'
  }
})
```

### index.html

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown="" ng-show="false">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Kyle Thomas</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span> <span class="sr-only">Split
      button!</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/setting">Setting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#/login">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this drop down should show when redirected to home.html!!

Thanks

Comment: I did't find any ng-hide Directive in your html code?

Comment: @chandu - sorry I had them mistakenly ng-hide, but I meant ng-show!

Comment: try my solution once. update your html with broadcast variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `ng-show` value `directly as false`. when scope updates the value not changed. so use the `$scope.dropdown` in `ng-show`

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown="" ng-show="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Kyle Thomas</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span> <span class="sr-only">Split
      button!</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/setting">Setting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#/login">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here the value of `ng-show` changes `angular automatically handle the ng-hide` directive.

```
if ng-show ="true" it shows the html
if ng-show = "false" it hides the html. here no need of ng-hide.
```

In your `controller` set the `$scope.dropdown = false;` `first`. It `hides the html`. when user `logins into your app` `change the value` of `$scope.dropdown = true;` `it shows the html`

Comment: it still doesn't work, even though I've it as : `$scope.dropdown = true`;

Comment: can you create some fiddle

Comment: what I essentially want is this menu to disappear on login page and appear on home page; simple!!!

Comment: are you using same controller for both are different

Comment: yes, its the loginCtrl for login.html, and I've this html in the index.html

Comment: Do you want me to have both `if ng-show="true" and if ng-show="false"` on a same line in the div element

Comment: index.html comes under what controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55202/discussion-between-simple-solution-and-chandu).